# Intersecting Curves with meshes

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

Is there a way to create a vertex at the intersection between a curve and a mesh?

I have a 3D model of an object that I want to detect in the real world using a point cloud. Since the point cloud is created from a depth sensor I figured that I would get better results if I could distribute the vertices in the model I have more evenly instead of having more vertices in the more detailed regions.

For this purpose I created a grid of lines (Bezier Curves) along the x, y and z axes. I tried converting them into a mesh and then using a Boolean intersect modifier but since the lines have no interior (or faces at all) I just get an empty mesh.
I also tried using cylinders instead of lines but, the geometry seems to be too complicated if I try to intersect with all the cylinders at once. And going through the intersections one by one is not an option because my grid is roughly 15x15x50 lines big.